# limited post-request size

Tags: http-post

We have a large input form with multiple jquery-generated tabs and lots and hidden fields. As long as the entire post-request is from the browser to the server is less than 32xxxx sign, everything goes well and all the fields are transmitted to the server.

Structure of our form:

- information (generated jquery)
- hidden-field and input-field (generated jquery) inside the Tabs
- hidden fields in the form at the bottom firmly into programmed

So now the tabs, jquery-hidden fields and jquery-input fields are written in the post-reqeust, but tranfer hidden fields sporadically only when the entire length of the requests is greater than sign 32xxxx. This is quite striking. So some fields are missing after transmission to the server in the post-request stream.

From the server, the form is filled and displayed in the backend of joomla and that's no problem. Then I change something on a tab (div name) or content (ul - li ... input type ...) and sends the whole back to the server. And now no longer get all the content in full. When you before sending it again checks the content in the DOM, all form fields are filled in correctly and nothing is cut off, so here jquery works flawlessly.

In an input-type field, entire novels are very long texts. Which are often completely transferred back to the server. But it cuts off the browser probably some other input-types. And these are then transferred to the server sporadically, if request-size is greater than 32xxxx sign.

You always hear of a limitation of input-field values​​. But do not assume it will be just like that input fields did not commit.

joomla admin form:

```
form action = "... our action ..." method = "post" name = "admin form" id = "profile-form" class = "form-validate"
```

What can it be? How can we achieve that all fields of the whole form by clicking on the submit button will transfer anyway?

Answer (score 0):

1. Would ensure my server doesn't reject the size of the request or trim it
2. Would ensure my php settings are correct post_max_size 20M (value is obviously an example)
3. If the problem persists I would partition the request and transmit smaller segments (pretty simple to do actually). But I'm pretty sure checking the server and php settings will resolve the issue ;)